# Button Names 'Click here' vs 'something else'

Tags: buttons, copywriting, users

We're having internal arguments about how to label buttons with actions. Other folks in the internet teams, who aren't necessarily User-Focused, demanding that 'Action' buttons to simply read "click here". Has anyone come across good articles / best practices for button naming? Need ammo for proving that users are more likely to click on buttons that indicate where that click will take them, i.e. "Contact Us Online".

Comment: Are you looking for the same info as [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink) or are you more specifically looking for how to name certain types of buttons?

Comment: So does that answer your question? Should I close this question as a duplicate of the linked question, or do you have something more specific to ask?

Answer (score 3):

What's the context of those buttons? In my mind, it makes even less sense to use 'Click here' as the text of a button that it does for a link because at least a link will normally be in context (i.e. "To find out more about XYZ, click here") whilst a button will almost always be a standalone object, to be clicked on. I can't imagine how a button can possibly have the words 'Click here' on it.

Comment: Yeah, the AFFORDANCE of the object should tell you WHAT you can DO with it.  And from a copywriting standpoint, you want to provide a BENEFIT to get them to click.  ( "Learn more" will beat "click here" every day of the week).